# Is there any way to delay ng-view?

Tags: angularjs

I have layout where I have:

```
<li ng-click="GetLoader();"><a href="../Account/#/PersonalInfo">ACCOUNT</a></li>
<li ng-click="GetLoader();"><a href="#">SETTINGS</a></li>
```

On the index page, I have a menu and ng-view where I can change pages on a click
Also included on the index page is a spinner.

```
<div class="loading" ng-show="ticketloading" ng-init="GetLoader()">
    <div>
        <img class="spinner" ng-src="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

In my script I have -

```
$scope.GetLoader = function() {
    $scope.ticketloading = true;
    loader.css("z-index", "1");
}
```

My problem is that when a user clicks on "Account" it gets loaded, but just for few milliseconds. Then it changes to all blank. I receive data from ng-view. My question is **how can I delay showing ng-view to show the loader a little bit longer.**
Thanx in advance!

Comment: You can play with the class `ng-enter` and put an animation on with the duration that you want.

Comment: And what code does hide the spinner?

Comment: setTimeout for putting the z-index to the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should avoid using DOM manipulations in controller. In your case it's better to use declarative ngClass directive to set opacity.

Then your actual issue is that you don't want to use static `setTimeout` to hide loaded, but rather listen `$routeChangeSuccess`:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $rootScope.ticketloading = false;
});
```

and use this loading flag in template like you are currently doing.

You can put above event listener in run block for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can add property in your controller, for example dataLoading and add ng-if attribute to ng-view like this:

layout

```
<div ng-view ng-if="!dataLoading">
```

controller

```
function loadData()
{
     var self = this;
     self.dataLoading = true;
     dataService.loadData(params, function(){
           ...
           self.dataLoading = false;
     });
}
```